# Why Sentry is not working in Java while the similar code working in python?

Tags: java, sentry

I am trying to integrate Sentry with our java project. I already tested a python script and it works fine. It looks like this:

```
from raven import Client

client = Client(myDsn)

try:
    1 / 0
except ZeroDivisionError:
    client.captureException()
```

But when I do the same thing in Java, it does't work. Java code looks like this:

```
  @Test
  public void Sentry() throws IOException {
    Sentry.init(dsn);
    Sentry.getContext().addExtra("stacktrace.app.packages", "com.testpackage.test");
    Sentry.getContext().setUser(new UserBuilder().setUsername("RoboTricker").build());
    Sentry.getContext().addTag("thread", Thread.currentThread().getName());

    try {
      unsafeMethod();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Sentry.capture(e);
    }
  }
```

There is no exception but when I go to the dashboard there is no error reported. That means its not sending the error.

The dsn for both code is same.
Any idea what I might be missing?

Comment: What maks you think that the java version does not work? Please describe symptoms.

Comment: @yunnosch There is no exception but when I go to the dashboard there is no error reported. That means its not sending the error.

Comment: Please add useful information to the question instead of hiding it in comments.

Comment: Can you try enabling DEBUG logging for `io.sentry` packages? Or try adding `?async=false` to your DSN. Also that isn't where `stacktrace.app.packages` or other configuration goes, see: https://docs.sentry.io/clients/java/config/

Comment: It worked with async=false. Seems like JVM exits early before the async process is completed in test environment. Thanks a lot.